# Add attributes inside custom attribute in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, dynamic-attributes

I want to dynamically add attributes to properties of a given class, because the project will get bigger and the procedure is totally repeatinglly, something like so :

```
public class MyAttr : Attribute {
    public MyAttr () {
        foreach(var prop in properties) {
            prop.Attributes.Add([Display(Name =  nameof(prop.Name), ResourceType = typeof(Labels))]);            
        }
    }
}
```

And use it on classes :

```
[MyAttr]
public class SomeClass {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

of course the code above is not a real program, but I tried to make it simple.

Is it possible to do this? or if not, is there a workaround?

**Update:** I know there's an attribute called `CallerMemberName` that retrieves name of a given property, but how to get the property itself and add more attributes to it?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to define a class with a generic property and the custom properties you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587236/generic-property-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Matt _ Maybe the link you mentioned is a part of the answer, but the other part is how to add more attributes to the property?

Comment: you would just add additional instance properties to the custom Generic property backed class.

Comment: I checked the what's new for C# 6 to 8 and could not find anything new. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8 (and the links to versions 6.0 - 7.3 are also there). Therefore, I think this may be achieved, painfully, using a custom type descriptor: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor?view=netframework-4.8 The first two sentences are promising: The ICustomTypeDescriptor interface allows an object to provide type information about itself. Typically, this interface is used when an object needs dynamic type information

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to make something work combining the below answers from other posts.

Access object properties from Attribute: [Can C# Attributes access the Target Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308020/can-c-sharp-attributes-access-the-target-class/2308028#2308028)

Add attributes at runtime: [How to add an attribute to a property at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-property-at-runtime/24413055#24413055) by creating new types at run-time.

Unless you're going to be making regular changes across all the properties it may just be better to deal with the repetitive work up front. There are inevitably risks/issues down the road when doing stuff across the board like this.

Comment: Note that suggested way prevents `new SomeClass (..)` calls as you'd need to create your instances via reflection using newly created type.