# Obtaining object reference from attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

It's possible to obtain a reference of the object that use an attribute?

E.g.:

```cs
public class Test {
    [MyAttribute]
    public string P {get;set;}
}
```

```cs
var k = new Test();

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void Invoke(){
        //Can I get here a reference to k at runtime?
    }
}
```

With `[CallerMemberName]` I can know which property calls the attribute but I don't know how to get the caller itself.

Comment: Nope, can't think of any way.

Comment: realistically, no, in theory you could use unsafe code to look through your entire application's memory looking for objects, and seeing if any of those objects have a property with that attribute.  It would be both very slow and extremely hard to do correctly though.

Comment: Attributes are for defining metadata related to the static definition of a method (among other things). I'm struggling to think of a situation where you would have access to that metadata without knowing what the metadata belonged to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can C# Attributes access the Target Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308020/11683)

Comment: There isn't an attribute per instance of the class, so there's nothing to tie the `MyAttribute` instance to the instance referred to by `k`.

Comment: _Objects_ don't use attributes. _Type definitions_ use attributes. Attributes are not associated with instances.