# Get type of decorated parameter in attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Having an attribute like this,

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class MyParamAttribute : Attribute { .. }
```

is there a way to get the type of the decorated parameter in the attribute implementation?

```cs
public void MyMethod([MyParam] string param) { .. }
```

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class MyParamAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ParamType => ...?
}
```

I wonder if there's a subtle way to get the type of the parameter apart from passing it directly by constructor.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class MyParamAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyParamAttribute(Type type) => ParamType = type;

    public Type ParamType { get; }
}

// ...
public void MyMethod([MyParam(typeof(string))] string param) { .. }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get it when you process the annotation. Is that not enough?

Comment: Short answer: **No**, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308028/159145 - [and please read the official docs too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes). - in short, attributes are declarative and are unaware of how and where they're used - that's the caller's responsibility (via `GetCustomAttributes()`).

Comment: Not really (at least don't know how). I am getting the attribute instance as an endpoint metadata from an HttpContext in a custom MVC middleware.

Comment: @VRoxa The endpoint metadata will give you the `MethodInfo` you can use to get `ParameterInfo` for each parameter, including each parameter's attributes - however _this whole thing smells fishy_ - why would a request middleware be doing this at all?